# why cassandra failover does no work?client retun error and lost data when node die

Tags: python, cassandra, client

i use python to test cassandra failover ,with cassandra driver [datastax python driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver)

cluster have 5 node and keyspace set to RF=3

client consistency_level set to QUORUM

```
cluster = Cluster(['172.17.35.45'])
session = cluster.connect('bigtest')
session.default_consistency_level = 4
```

and the insert script:

```
for seq in range(1000000, 2000000, 1):
timeStamp=int(round(time.time() * 1000))
c_data=uuid.uuid1()
upseq=None
try:
    session.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO bigtest (seq, insert_time, c_data,upseq)
    VALUES (%(seq)s, %(insert_time)s, %(content_data)s,%(upseq)s)
    """,
    {'seq': seq, 'insert_time': timeStamp, 'content_data': c_data,'upseq': upseq}
    )
except Exception,e:
    logging.error(e)
    logging.error(seq)
```

1. running script,kill one node's cassandra process use 'ps aux | grep cassandra | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill -9' and nodetool status show server node status is DN . then the scripts work fine and no data lost
2. running script,unplug one node's ethernet cable.then client report error and data was no inserted

`2017-08-10 09:50:35,572 [ERROR] root: errors={'172.17.35.46': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'}, last_host=172.17.35.46
2017-08-10 09:50:35,572 [ERROR] root: 1065075`

and this is full log without try exp:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert_test.py", line 28, in <module>
    {'seq': seq, 'insert_time': timeStamp, 'content_data': c_data,'upseq': upseq}
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2016, in execute
    return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state).result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3826, in result
    raise self._final_exception
cassandra.OperationTimedOut: errors={'172.17.35.46': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'}, last_host=172.17.35.46`

why and how to resolve it thank you all.

Comment: What replication factor are you using on the keyspace, and what does `default_consistency_level = 4` map to in your driver ?

Comment: replication_factor=3 and default_consistency_level=QUORUM [consistency_level](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra.html#cassandra.ConsistencyLevel)

Comment: What node is unplug cable for (in the second scenario)? Is it the same node which is tried to be queried by the client? I think, in the second scenario you have a splitted cluster where one part consist of 4 nodes and another part consist of 1 node, and when you tries to query the second part of the splitted cluster, CL=quorum can not be reached.